# qsort funcation work with structre which carry char poiter member

Tags: c, qsort

I can't understand following qsort call `qsort(cricketer,7,sizeof(struct player),comp);`

How is the size of "struct player" calculated because in struct player member char `*name;` is not static.

```
struct player
{
    char* name;
    int age, ntm, ar;
}

cricketer[20]={
                "sam",35,10,300,
                "ram",55,15,200,
                "aman",45,19,300,
                "raman",65,22,400,
                "mani",75,25,350,
                "mono",76,10,215,
                "verma",88,16,103
    };
int comp(const void* a,const void* b)
{
    const struct player * x = (const struct player*)a;
    const struct player * y = (const struct player*)b;
    if(x->age > y->age)return 1;
    else return 0;
}

void read()
{
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    printf("\n\t\tName : %s\t\tAge : %d\t\tNum of Matches : %d\t\tTotal score : %d\n\n ", cricketer[i].name, cricketer[i].age, cricketer[i].ntm, cricketer[i].ar);
}

int main()
{
    read();
    printf("\n\t\tAfter Qsort : %d\n", sizeof(struct player));
    qsort(cricketer,7,sizeof(struct player),comp);
    read();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to read more about the standard [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort), especially what the comparison function should return.

Comment: It's the size of 3 ints and a char pointer plus any padding added between elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters this comparison function

```
int comp(const void *a,const void *b)
{
    const struct player *x=(const struct player*)a; const struct player *y=(const struct player*)b;
    if(x->age > y->age)return 1;



    else return 0;
}
```

is invalid. It shall return three values: a positive, a negative or zero depending on compared values. But the function returns only two values: either 1 or 0.

The structure contains four members

```
struct player{
    char *name;
    int age,ntm,ar;
};
```

So its size is calculated like `sizeof( char * )` + `sizeof( int )` + `sizeof( int )` + `sizeof( int )` + a posible `padding` for alignment.

That is the size of the structure is known at the compile time independent on what string is pointed to by the data member `name`. The string pointed to by the data member `name` is not a member of the structure. For example the pointer can be initialized by NULL.

Answer (score 0):

The structure contains the *pointer* `name`, not the memory that the pointer might actually point to. Therefore the size is well-known as it only include the size of the pointer itself.

Comment: if size is well-known as it only include the size of the pointer itself then whom decide start and end point of any one structure in array of structure in qsort

Comment: @megat You have an array of `struct player`. Each element in the array is `sizeof(struct player)` bytes large. And arrays are *contiguous* which means the structures follows each other in the array. `cricketer[0]` is the first element, it's *directly* followed by `cricketer[1]` which is exactly `sizeof(struct player)` bytes after the start of `cricketer[0]`.

Comment: @megat If you print the pointers to the elements, you will see that the difference between e.g. `&cricketer[1]` and `&cricketer[0]` is exactly `sizeof(struct player)` bytes. And the `qsort` function uses the element size to know where each element in the array starts. From the start of the array it can add a multiple of `sizeof(struct player)` to get to an arbitrary element in the array.